# Place the data of the periodic table excerpt correctly in a TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, tikz-matrix

[image]

I have a small excerpt from a periodic table.

Now I want to place the symbols (2nd column) correctly in a TikZ matrix with 8 rows and 18 columns; where unoccupied cells should remain empty.

For what I say:

```
\pgfmathsetglobalmacro\PeriodGroupTest{
\PeriodNo==\Row && \GroupNo==\Col ?  1 : 0  }
```

Somehow, with my method, only the very first entry is correct. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

By the way: With the listing of the test data it always gets bigger than any paper size, so I had to set strange values ​​for document and font size.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{psetest.csv}
Z; Symbol; Period; Group
1; H; 1; 1
2; He; 1; 18
4; Be; 2; 2
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[paper=A2, fontsize=2pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=1mm, landscape, showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\pgfmathsetglobalmacro#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \global\let#1\pgfmathresult}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, col sep=semicolon]{psetest.csv}{\psetable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\psetable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach[evaluate={\Row=int(\row+1)}] \row in {0,...,7}{%%
\foreach[evaluate={\Col=int(\col+1)}] \col in {0,...,17}{%
% Group and Period
\ifnum\row<3% Here for the test-table ====
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Period}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\PeriodNo{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Group}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\GroupNo{\pgfplotsretval}
% PeriodGroupTest
\pgfmathsetglobalmacro\PeriodGroupTest{
\PeriodNo==\Row && \GroupNo==\Col ?  1 : 0  }
\fi%==========
% Insert Symbol
\ifnum\PeriodGroupTest=1%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\symbol{\pgfplotsretval}
%
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{\symbol, 
r\row c\col, R\Row C\Col, p\PeriodNo, g\GroupNo, pgt\PeriodGroupTest \expandonce{\&}  }
\else%
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{X, 
r\row c\col, R\Row C\Col, p\PeriodNo, g\GroupNo, pgt\PeriodGroupTest \expandonce{\&}  }
\fi%
}%
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}%%

\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
label={PSE}] (m){
\mymatrixcontent 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: pgfplotstable might not be the best tool for this because `\pgfplotstablegetelem` is inefficient and it stores the data in columns and not rows. I'd either go through all rows once and save everything in custom value keys, i.e. `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pt/p1/g1/name}{H}\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pt/p1/g1/Z}{1}\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pt/p1/g1/<attribute>}{<value>}` and then just look those value up for each cell inside the matrix i.e. `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pt/\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow/\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn/<attribute>}`.

Comment: Or alternatively, just go through each row and place what ever you need to place at `(<group>, -<period>)` and adjust *xy*  coordinate system so that it fits. It looks like each element entry should have the same height and width anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{psetest.csv}
Z; Symbol; Period; Group
1; H; 1; 1
2; He; 1; 18
%3; Li; 2; 1
4; Be; 2; 2
% ...
14; Si; 3; 14
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[paper=A4, %fontsize=2pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm, landscape, showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\def\pgfmathsetglobalmacro#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \global\let#1\pgfmathresult}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, col sep=semicolon]{psetest.csv}{\psetable}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\psetable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\psetableLastRowNo{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\def\Showvalues{1}

\def\symbol{Xyz}
\def\GroupNo{0}
\def\PeriodNo{0}
\def\PeriodGroupTest{0}
 
 
 
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\psetable}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\foreach \row in {1,...,8}{%%
\foreach \col in {1,...,18}{%
% Group and Period
\foreach \tablerow in {0,...,\psetableLastRowNo}{%===========
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\tablerow}{Period}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\PeriodNo{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\tablerow}{Group}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\GroupNo{\pgfplotsretval}
% PeriodGroupTest
\pgfmathsetglobalmacro\PeriodGroupTest{
\PeriodNo==\row && \GroupNo==\col ?  1 : 0  }
% Insert Symbol
\ifnum\PeriodGroupTest=1%
\breakforeach% <---- ?
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\tablerow}{Symbol}\of{\psetable}
\xdef\symbol{\pgfplotsretval}
\xdef\Fill{red}
\xdef\Draw{blue}
%\breakforeach% <---- ?
\else%
\xdef\symbol{}
\xdef\Fill{none}
\xdef\Draw{none}
\fi%
}%==============
\xappto\mymatrixcontent{|[fill=\Fill, draw=\Draw]|{\symbol 
\ifnum\Showvalues=1 \\ r\row c\col \\  p\PeriodNo g\GroupNo \\ pgt\PeriodGroupTest \fi}
\expandonce{\&}  }
}%
\gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}%%

\matrix[matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
nodes={align=center, 
text width=8mm,
}, 
column sep=0em, 
%label={PSE}
] (m){
\mymatrixcontent 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```